# Replace slashes in a filename

Tags: bash, shell-script

So I need to write a bash script that copies all files to a specified directory however I need to rename the files to it's absolute path by replacing the `/` character with `__`.

For example if the file `zad1.sh` is in the directory `/home/123456/` the file needs to be renamed to `__home__123456__zad1.sh`

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: *all files* - from where? Add some pseudo-code

Comment: Please, show us what you tried so far.

Comment: Presuming this is _for_ something, how are you going to handle the case of `some__really__important_file.txt` when putting things back not going into `/path/to/some/really/important_file.txt`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Good point. For example Python projects might have files named `__init__.py`, `__main__.py`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The classic approach would be to use sed:

```
cp "${filename}" "$(realpath ${filename} | sed s:/:__:g)"
```

The advantage is primarily portability across shells if you won't necessarily always be using bash.

Of course, it also lets you forego the script and just do it with find:

```
find /base/path -type f -exec cp \{\} `realpath \{\} | sed s:/:__:g` \;
```

Find has sorting and filtering options you can use if you need them to only copy certain files.

edit:  That find setup works on one of my systems, but not on the other one.  Rather than sort out the difference, I just made it more portable:

```
find /base/path -type f | sed -e "p; s:/:__:g" | xargs -n2 cp
```

Comment: That `find` command will not work. The backticks will be evaluated before `find` and get you basically the equivalent of `$PWD/{}` with the slashes in `$PWD` replaced with double underscores. So, if you're in `/home/user`, this is equivalent to: `find /base/path -exec cp {} __home__user__{} \;` If you have a file `f` in `/base/path`, this will try to copy it to `__home__user__/base/path/f`.

Comment: @JoL  It worked when I tested it...  I'll test it again when I get a few minutes...

Comment: `find -exec sh -c 'cp "$1" "$(realpath "$1" | sed s:/:__:g)"' sh {} \;` should do

Comment: `xargs` will have issues with names with whitespace, unless you use `find -print0 | sed -z | xargs -0` (with at least GNU sed). Also any of those will make the copies to the current directory, which may or may not be what you want.

Comment: @Perkins "That find setup works on one of my systems" I have a hard time imagining how that could work anywhere. The only edge case I can kind of see is if your current working directory **is** `/base/path` and you just have regular files in there, no directories. However, even then you'd be copying to e.g. `/base/path/__base__path__./f`. That's not right.

Comment: Besides that problem, something that no one has mentioned and that is present even in the `xargs` version is that you'll also be trying to copy directories inside `/base/path`. `cp` will complain that you can't do that unless you supply `-r`, but you shouldn't do that. Instead, you should supply `-type f` to `find`, so that it will only output regular files under the hierarchy.

Comment: @JoL I'm not sure why it works on the one system myself yet.  Obviously something about the environment is causing bash to defer execution of the backticks, but I haven't managed to isolate what it is.  I've noticed that sometimes this one defers glob expansion as well depending on what command is being run, so possibly it's something in the bash completions or some similar setting changing the way it parses the command.  If I figure it out I'll add it to the answer.

Answer (score 18):

To get the path of your file :

```
realpath <file>
```

Replace in bash:

```
echo "${var//search/replace}"
```

The first two slashes are for making global search. Using just `/` would only do one replacement.

So your code could be

```
path=$(realpath zad1.sh)
path_replaced=${path//\//__}
```

Answer (score 6):

I believe this will accomplish what you are asking:

```
#!/bin/bash

_from_dir=/path/to/files
_to_dir=/path/to/dest

for file in "${_from_dir}/"*; do
    nfile="$(sed 's#/#__#g' <<<"$file")"
    cp "$file" "${_to_dir}/$nfile"
done
```

Set the `_from_dir` variable to the path where your files are located and the `_to_dir` variable to the path where you want them copied.

The loop will go through each file in the `_from_dir` location.  `nfile` will take the full path of the file and replace `/` with `__`.  Then it will `cp` the file into the `_to_dir` path with a name representing the full path of it's origin.

Answer (score 0):

I have done by below method

```
ls -ltr /root/l.txt| awk '{print "cp" " " $NF,$NF}'| awk '{gsub("/","_",$NF);print $1,$2,"/root/p1/"$3}'| sh
```

Here file /root/l.txt will be copied to /root/p1/ path but filename will be _root_l.txt Let me know for any confusion

```
Here /root/p1==> destination path
```